# Jquery .html method hangs on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, mobile

I'm having a hard time implementing an Ajax-navigation on an Android app. It works like a charm on the desktop and on the iPhone, but fails on Android. Here is the current implementation:

```
function ajaxnav(href, params, meth){
    if(typeof params === "undefined"){
        params = {}
    }
    if(typeof meth === "undefined"){
        meth = "get"
    }
    $(".loading").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        type: meth,
        data: params,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXhr){
            $(".round").html(data)
        $(".loading").hide();
            $(".inner-content a").each(function(i){
            ajaxlinkbuilder($(this));
        })
        ajaxnavchange = true;
        History.pushState(null, "AppName", href);
        if(isAndroid()) myScroll.refresh();
        },
        error: function(data, textStatus, jqXhr){
            window.location = href;
        }
    })
    return false;
}
```

It won't work even if I put

```
            $(".loading").hide();
            $(".inner-content a").each(function(i){
                ajaxlinkbuilder($(this));
            })
            ajaxnavchange = true;
            History.pushState(null, "AppName", href);
            if(isAndroid()) myScroll.refresh();
```

inside a `promise().done()` block. It simply sticks during the execution of `.html()`. I tried waiting to see if it's just a slowdown due to various reasons but I've been waiting for 10 minutes and it doesn't even call the first line after - the `$(".loading").hide()`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you check what's inside data on Android ? Did you check it's really hanging in html(data) and not later ?

Comment: Yes, I checked it's really hanging in html(data). I put some alerts for debugging right before and right after html(data) and the one after wasn't called.